# Web Audio loops with <audio> as source

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I understand that I can manipulate the audio stream with Web Audio using createMediaElementSource() but is it possible to play / loop the audio with Web Audio and use the  tag purely for loading the audio?

This is what I tried but it says start() is not a function:

```
window.onload = init;
var context;
var bufferLoader;

function init() {
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    context = new AudioContext();

    var audio = $("audio").get(0);
    var source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.start(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.onload = init;

function init() {
    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

    var context = new AudioContext();

    var audio = $("audio").get(0);

    audio.addEventListener('loadstart', function() {
        var source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
        source.connect(context.destination);

        audio.play(0);
    }, false);
}
```

Refer to https://github.com/Korilakkuma/XSound/blob/master/build/xsound.dev.js#L9703 in [XSound.js](https://github.com/Korilakkuma/XSound)

Answer (score 0):

You can start playing the audio with `audio.play()` but your source is a MediaElementAudioSourceNode, not an AudioBufferSourceNode.

If you find a way to get the buffer of the audio tag, maybe you can pass it to an AudioBuffer and make it works...

Answer (score -1):

How about you try the "" command on html? 
It's written like so:

```
    <audio controls preload> </li>
    <source src="the/source/in/your/library">
    </audio>
```

More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)

Comment: Ummm.. I'm having trouble understanding this reply.

Comment: there is this thing in html called audio

Comment: <audio controls preload loop>

Comment: I'm sorry if its confusing

Comment: I don't want to use <audio>'s loop. I want to use Web Audio's loop. I want to use the <audio> as the source for Web Audio.